Cannot import JS library opus-recorder in TypeScript project
In my Vite TypeScript React application I'm trying to import the Opus Recorder library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/opus-recorder).
I have set this flag in tsconfig.json:
  "compilerOptions": {

    "allowJs": true,

and imported this library in my index.tsx in this way:
import * as opus from '../../../node_modules/opus-recorder/dist/recorder.min.js';

but when I try to invoke the constructor:
const recorder = new opus.Recorder({ encoderSampleRate: 44100 });

I get TypeError: opus.Recorder is not a constructor.
I tried creating a declaration file using tsc:
tsc --declaration --allowJs --outFile types/opus-recorder.d.ts node_modules/opus-recorder/dist/recorder.min.js

but this throws:
error TS5056: Cannot write file '/Users/dade/powercor/llm_experiment/client/types/opus-recorder.d.ts' because it would be overwritten by multiple input files

I manually created a type declaration file in types/index.d.ts:
declare module 'opus-recorder' {
  // Recorder Configuration Interface
  interface RecorderConfig {
    bufferLength?: number;
    encoderApplication?: number;
    encoderFrameSize?: number;
    encoderPath?: string;
    encoderSampleRate?: number;
    maxFramesPerPage?: number;
    mediaTrackConstraints?: boolean | MediaTrackConstraints; // Allow flexible input
    monitorGain?: number;
    numberOfChannels?: number;
    recordingGain?: number;
    resampleQuality?: number;
    streamPages?: boolean;
    wavBitDepth?: number;
    sourceNode?: { context: AudioContext | null } | MediaStreamAudioSourceNode;
  }

  // Recorder Class
  class Recorder {
    // Static Methods
    static isRecordingSupported(): boolean;

    // Constructor
    constructor(config?: RecorderConfig);

    // Instance Properties
    state: "inactive" | "loading" | "recording" | "paused";  // Possible states
    config: RecorderConfig;
    encodedSamplePosition: number;

    // Instance Methods (simplified for brevity)
    initAudioContext(): void;
    initWorklet(): Promise<void>;
    initEncoder(): Promise<void>;
    initialize: Promise<void>; // Combined promise for initWorklet & initEncoder
  }

  export default Recorder;
}

but I get the same error: TypeError: opus.Recorder is not a constructor.
Can someone please help me?
